# Can Sonatype Nexus resolve dependencies multiple levels deep?

Tags: dependency-management, nexus, sonatype

I just got the following question from a developer. I know Nexus can manage this through Maven, but don't have experience with .Net applications. Maybe it's managed by NuGet?

> I just want to ensure that Nexus can resolve dependencies multiple
>   levels deep.
>
> So for example... I have a project, which depends on dll "A".  This
>   has two dependencies itself, dlls "B" and "C".  "B" then also depends
>   on "D", which itself depends on "E".
>
> I need to know that when our project references dll "A", that Nexus
>   will not only install the correct version of this, but also dlls "B",
>   "C", "D" and "E".
>
> Essentially, it must know how to resolve the entire dependency tree,
>   infinite levels deep, not just the immediate dependency, which in this
>   example would just be "A".  I do believe Nexus can do this,
>   Artifactory made a point of mentioning this in the demo, so I simply
>   want to ensure that Nexus does indeed have the same functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you install a NuGet package from Nexus, your nuget client (e.g. the nuget cmdline client, or Visual Studio) makes a request to Nexus repository, and then it makes follow-up requests for all of the dependencies, which Nexus will also supply.